# Performances of reverse_iterator vs iterator?

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, iterator, c++14

I am designing a very efficient iterator for a High Performance Computing / Supercomputer application. I was wondering whether the `std::reverse_iterator` adaptor will introduce some overhead or whether it is likely to compile and achieve the exact same performances as the iterator type it is applied to.

Comment: You can glance at the implementation of `std::reverse_iterator` in the standard library. It's a pretty thin wrapper and it doesn't look like it introduces any overhead (pretty sure that the Standard Committee thought about this for a long time and they designed it with the zero-overhead principle in mind).

Comment: @vsoftco: There is no implementation "in the standard library". There is one in the *implementation of the standard library* that the OP uses. Whether it introduces overhead or not (and whether that's likely or not) is QoI issue. It is by all means possible for a conforming C++ implementation to make reverse iteration slower. The question thus does not make much sense, because it does not mention which compiler and which standard-library implementation we are talking about.

Comment: reverse iterator can be C-pointer which gets decremented and it can be fully built class with some complex logic. unless asking on specific standard container we cannot answer this question.

Comment: While _all_ the comments above, the 'answer' and comments therein are valid, just keep in mind that modern processor's cache prefetchers are smart in detecting your access patterns and getting the right memory in. This however, is intuition. And intuition when talking about performance is wrong, unless proven to be right with a _lot_ of measement.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Of course, that's what I meant by "glancing at the implementation". The C++ standard is an abstraction that specifies the complexity, not the details. But I'd be really surprised if a reverse iterator introduces any overhead. Any student can write such a wrapper with basically zero overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to performance, don't guess, don't ask, **measure**. And don't measure with artificial small test programs. Measure speed with your real code, your real application, your real data on real target machines.

C++ as a language does not make any guarantees as to whether `std::reverse_iterator` introduces overhead or not. The question would be a bit more answerable if you at least told us which compiler and which compiler options you are using, because the performance of standard-library facilities (algorithmic complexity requirements aside) is a quality-of-implementation (QoI) issue. It's unlikely that you would experience a difference in performance with `std::reverse_iterator`, but who knows?

You also have not told us anything about the underlying iterator that you want to adapt. It may, for instance, be an iterator into a custom container and have different performance characteristics for `--` and `++`.

Comment: This is not an answer; it is a comment (albeit an apt one).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's a corner case :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it depends on whether you read the question as *"will `std::reverse_iterator` make my program slower?"* or simply as *"how could `std::reverse_iterator` make my program slower?"*. The second interpretation is somewhat answerable.